# Calculating complex roots: method to find them all

Tags: complex-analysis

I am calculating some complex roots and I did two and one I got right and **the other one I also got right** **but not with my original method**.

Concretely, I calculated $z^6 = 1$ by writing $e^{i6\varphi} = e^{i 2 \pi}$ so that the first solution is $\varphi = {2\pi \over 6} = {\pi \over 3}$.

Then I thought all the multiples of this are also solutions so solutions are:

${\pi \over 3}, {2\pi \over 3}, \pi, {4\pi \over 3}, {5\pi \over 3}, 0$.

I then checked that this is correct and moved on to solving $z^4 = -1$.

I first tried to do it the same way getting $\varphi = {\pi \over 4}$.

But then ${2\pi \over 4 } = {\pi \over 2}$ is already not a solution because ${4\pi \over 2 } = 2 \pi$ which is $1$ not $-1$.

> What is my mistake in thinking here? Why does my original method not work for the second equation?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's not the *multiples* of $\varphi$ that give solutions.  The fact that this worked for $z^6 = 1$ is just a coincidence (because the RHS is $1$).  What you want to do for $z^4 = -1$ is this:

\begin{align*}
  z^4 &= -1\\
  e^{4i\varphi} &= e^{i\pi + 2ki\pi}\\
  4i\varphi &= i\pi + 2ik\pi\\
  \varphi &= \frac\pi4 + \frac{k\pi}2
\end{align*}
where $k=0,1,2,3$.  So then
$$ z = e^{i\pi/4}, e^{3i\pi/4}, e^{5i\pi/4}, e^{7i\pi/4}$$

Comment: Oh yes, of course! Now I remember. Thank you for reminding me! I knew that but somehow I ended up calculating multiples. Duh!

Comment: @student, you're welcome!  When solving $z^6 = 1$ it works out to be multiples coincidentally because the equation becomes $e^{6i\varphi} = e^{0 + 2ki\pi}$.  The $0$ there (where we have $i\pi$ in $z^4 = -1$) is what causes it to be multiples.

Answer (score 1):

Given the argument $a_0$ of the principal solution to $z^n=k$, the other solutions' arguments are *not* multiples of $a_0$. Instead, they are obtained by *adding* multiples of $\frac{2\pi}n$ to $a_0$; when the power of $n$ is applied these extra multiples add up to some multiple of $2\pi$ and therefore leave the argument unchanged.

The "multiples of $a_0$" idea only works when $k$ in the equation above is a *positive* real number.